# Ground Pour in Power Supply PCB

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, grounding, linear

I'm designing and building a linear power supply for my tube headphone amplifier. Considering this should be HiFi, I'm trying to make it as good as it gets within "normal" building costs and without building a discrete regulator.

That being said and done, I think I have finalised the schematic (any feedback would be welcomed really). Now, I am working on the layout and I'm trying to decide between using a ground pour or a star ground topology. PCB will be single sided (etched at home), so considering layout simplicity, a ground pour would be advantageous, but I would not want this to deter performance. From what I read, it might not matter so much in this particular in this implementation, as I'm not dealing with RF frequencies, but I'm open to any ideas still.[image]

Comment: Just checking.  This power supply will sit on its own board.  It will not be a part of a larger board with analog signal chain, power amp, and so on.  Right?

Comment: You are correct, board will be separate from the rest of the audio parts, hence the second (output) connector on the right. To be more specific, the power supply board will have 3 separate rails (coming from separate secondaries) which will supply the amp, a usb receiver and some DAC chips.

Comment: The board is too small to have an appreciable difference using either topology. Any reason why you are keeping it a separate board and not buying a 12V wall wart?

Comment: Well, because the amp is susceptible to noise on the power line, a switching supply is out of the question (tried one for the initial tests and it hummed horribly)

Comment: Have you breadboarded the circuit? It would be very easy and would be very comparable due to the simplicity of the circuit. This will allow you to try different capacitor/inductor filtering options on the output. Then you might be able to integrate it in with your amp PCB. Right now the connector and wire leads just acts a weak inductor and theoretically does little for noise filtering.

Also not all switching supplies are made equal and output filtering goes a long way. Power supply design is an art.

Comment: I didn't breadboard it as I'm still waiting for the mains transformer. Also, considering I need multiple voltage rails, a smps is just not an option (not for hifi anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ground pour is all fine and good, but don't make the high AC current traces part of the ground pour.

In particular, the conductor between the large 4700uF filter capacitor and the bridge rectifier should be a separate conductor and not through the ground pour. Similarly run the trace from the regulator +Vin to the capacitor and thence to the bridge. You may wish to put capacitors across the bridge diodes.

2M2 for the pot? How many volts is this supposed to be? That's about 12kV if I did the math right. You using hydrogen thyratrons?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are suggesting I start the ground pour after the big filter cap, or in any case after the rectifier. I have thought about a cap across the rectifier as well, but it seems choosing a soft-recovery bridge would render it useless.

Comment: PS: Great spot on the trimmer. I botched my calculations by an order of magnitude. It should output around 12.6V for the tube heater and B+

Comment: After the input filter cap, especially the big one. High current double-mains-frequency pulses will be conducted between the bridge and the capacitor and you don't want those creating voltage gradients across your pour. You can also notch the pour to keep currents flowing where you want them.

Comment: How do you notch the pour? I'm not familiar with this term.

Comment: Suppose you have a pour that would allow current to flow over to the other side of the board, where you don't want it to flow. You can insert a keepout polygon, line or other such feature that prevents the pour from propagating where you don't want it to go, or overlap pour areas, leaving gaps in certain places. Think about the high current and how it flows..

Answer (score 1):

Star ground won't give you much in this supply. On the other hand, a pour will provide large copper area helping in heat transfer. Just make sure not to extend the pour to areas where low-level analog signals are present or better yet make this supply a separate unit and connect it to the load with a pair of wires.

Comment: The board will be physically separated from the audio pcb, so no issues there.